# Running NArrange from SVN pre-commit hook

Tags: svn, hook, pre-commit

I am trying to execute [NArrange](http://sourceforge.net/projects/narrange/) from SVN pre-commit hook using following command:

```
"C:\Fullpath\narrange-console.exe" "C:\SolutionDir\SolutionFile.sln" /b /t
```

It returns with an Error: "The hook script returned an error: "

Any one any at rescue? 

**EDIT:** This hook are tortoisesvn client hooks.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-commit hook is evaluated on the repository server; not on the client. And pre-commit hooks can't change what is to be committed. (They can only deny a commit if it is not valid for some rules).

You could look at tortoisesvn client hooks, or at a post commit that does a cleanup commit when a file changes. (But make sure you don't get in an endless loop :))