# how to configure NArrange with svn

Tags: svn, configuration

Does anyone know how to configure svn so that every file committed is run on [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/narrangemojo/doc/index.htm#using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680886/running-narrange-from-svn-pre-commit-hook) you cannot do this on the server. You could use a client hook but not every client supports this. (TortoiseSvn does)

Comment: Dear Stefan,Thanks for the information
Can you give me detail like where to look for client hook if possible?

Comment: I am just looking for a hook which will NArrange the files which are going to be committed.

Comment: I never did this myself. You can find samples here:
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/svn/tortoisesvn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/client-side/

(login with guest, no password). One thing that is important: The scripts are not saved in the repository. You have to "install" them on every machine that should use them...

Comment: Thats what i am looking for ,I want a client side working tool.I dont mind installing/configuring @ every developers place.Thanks a lot stefan.Will try this out .+1 :)